# Ionic Firebase Facebook login works fine in browser, but not on Android

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am relatively new to Ionic and I'm having issues doing a Facebook login with ionic framework on the android platform. It does work perfectly on browser (sometimes when I try to do the login the first attempt doesn't work) but when I run the project on Android it just redirects and doesn't pass to the next page.

I think that the issue could be that the first login attempt doesn't fetch the Facebook user data.

Here is my code:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function (Backand, $state, $rootScope, $scope, LoginService, ID, name) {

$scope.bgs = ["img/welcome-bg.jpg"];

$scope.firebaseFacebookLogIn = function(){

    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('user_birthday');
    provider.addScope('public_profile');
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        var uid = user.providerData[0].uid;
        var nombre = user.providerData[0].displayName;
        localStorage.setItem("Usuario", user);
        localStorage.setItem("ID", uid);
        localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nombre);
        $state.go('app.feed');
    }

    //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
          alert(errorCode);
        var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorMessage);
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
          alert(email);
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
          alert(credential);
        // ...
    });
};

$scope.ID = localStorage.getItem("ID");
$scope.name = localStorage.getItem("name");

$scope.facebookLogOut = function(token){
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
      $state.go('auth.walkthrough');
    }, function(error) {
    // An error happened.
    });

};

})
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Move your getRedirectResult outside scope.firebaseFacebookLogIn function. It should be call once the page load

Comment: It still redirects to the login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Turns out that I was just missing a  firebase tag inside config.xml of the project.. Pretty dumb to be honest, hope it helps to somebody with the same issue.